# Downloadmanager that sends downloads to remote server

Tags: linux, macos, mac, download, download-manager

i'm looking for a downloadmanager or browser plugin that is able to send download-urls to a remote location.

In detail I want to start downloads of large files (video files from an online vcr) on a mac os browser. Those download requests should then be downloaded by a remote linux server instead of the local client so i can shut down my workstation leaving the server to download the files.

Any help would be apprectiated;
Thanks

Comment: You could make a hack by telling FlashGot to use a custom program, and have the custom program be a script or something that does the forwarding for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the suggestion from Kovensky on this one.

Actually i got FlashGot and configured it to use a little Shellscript to download a File. The Shellscript containing this:

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh vault.local "wget --content-disposition -P /data/_NEW -b \"$1\""
```

This will effectively, for every URL that comes in through FlashGot, ssh into the server and issue a wget command for the download there.

SSH should work without a password (public-key authentication) for this.

Comment: thank for you help , that help me so much